# Regularity estimate: $\|u\|_{H^{k+1}(\Omega)} \leq C\left(\|f\|_{H^{k-1}(\Omega)} + \|g\|_{H^{k+1/2}(\partial \Omega)} \right)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $L$ be a uniformly strongly elliptic second order differential operator with coefficients in $W^{k+1,\infty}$, $f \in H^{k-1}(\Omega)$ and  $u_{|\partial \Omega} \in H^{k+1/2}(\partial \Omega)$. Consider the problem:

$$
\begin{split}
Lu &= f \quad \text{in } \Omega\\
     u &= g \quad \text{on } \partial \Omega,
\end{split}
$$

can someone tell me if this estimate is true?

$$\|u\|_{H^{k+1}(\Omega)} \leq C\left(\|f\|_{H^{k-1}(\Omega)} + \|g\|_{H^{k+1/2}(\partial \Omega)} \right)$$

especially for $k=1$:

$$\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq C\left(\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|g\|_{H^{3/2}(\partial \Omega)} \right)$$

Comment: If $\Omega$ is bounded (and sufficiently regular), then yes. Otherwise no. What are the assumptions on $\Omega$? Also, is $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: i am not sure, how smooth does $\Omega$ has to be? can you please give me a reference to that estimate? Yes $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The books "Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications" by Lions and Magenes is a classic reference. I am sure your will find the estimate in Vol. 1 of the series. The estimate is probably also in the book of Evans called "Partial Differential Equations". Also a very good book is "Partial Differential Equations" by Wloka, where the smoothness assumptions are probably sharp.

Comment: Concerning the smoothness of $\Omega$: $C^{k+1}$ is enough.